# Wrapping a script in a call function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tumblr-themes

I have a script im currently using, the issue is that i have to add the script directly after every html img tag. So there is the same script in several different places throughout the site. I am wondering if it is possible to wrap this script in a simple function call, and i can just add the function throughout the site instead of the whole script.

EDIT: I should have mentioned. This is a lightbox for a Tumblr theme.  photo_{PostID} is valid. photo_{PostID} retrieves the unique photo identifier so the lightbox will display the correct image. The script right now works 100% perfectly fine no doubt about that. I'm looking to turn it all into a simple 1 liner call function to use instead of needing to paste the script after every img tag.
the script is below, thanks.

```
    <script class="inline_embed" type="text/javascript">
        var domain = document.domain,
        photo_{PostID} = [{
            "width": "{PhotoWidth-HighRes}",
            "height": "{PhotoHeight-HighRes}",
            "low_res": "{PhotoURL-250}",
            "high_res": "{PhotoURL-HighRes}"
        }];

        function event_is_alt_key(e) {
            return ((!e && window.event && (window.event.metaKey || window.event.altKey)) || (e && (e.metaKey || e.altKey)));
        };

        document.getElementById('photo_{PostID}').onclick = function (e) {
            if (event_is_alt_key(e)) return true;
            window.parent.Tumblr.Lightbox.init(photo_{PostID});
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: What is this thing `photo_{PostID}`

Comment: I should have mentioned. This is a lightbox for a Tumblr theme.  photo_{PostID} is valid. photo_{PostID} retrieves the unique photo identifier so the lightbox will display the correct image. The script right now works 100% perfectly fine no doubt about that. I'm looking to turn it all into a simple 1 liner call function to use instead of needing to paste the script after every img tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged this question with [jquery] so I'm going to give an answer using jquery, even though your sample code doesn't use it.

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/u2f2b5qq/

Given a few images on the page, like this:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/250x150">
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x250">
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
<img src="http://placehold.it/150x50">
```

You can do some action on all of them once the page loads, like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('img').each(function() {
        $(this).on('click', function() {
            alert('You clicked ' + $(this).attr('src'));
            // window.parent.Tumblr.Lightbox.init(this);
        });
    });
});
```

What I've done is attach a `click` handler to every image and `alert` when it's clicked. You would replace that with your lightbox code.

---

I don't have a full understanding of how tumblr does its magic with interpolating those values, but I assume you could do something like this for each image. It attaches the Photo data to each image element, and then retrieves it later.

```
<img src="example.jpg" id="photo_{PostID}" data-width="{PhotoWidth-HighRes}" data-height="{PhotoHeight-HighRes}" data-low_res="{PhotoURL-250}" data-high_res="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" />
```

and then in the jquery kickoff:

```
$(function() {
    $('img').on('click', function() {
        var $img = $(this);
        alert('You clicked ' + $img.attr('src'));
        window.parent.Tumblr.Lightbox.init({
            width: $img.data('width'),
            height: $img.data('height'),
            low_res: $img.data('low_res'),
            high_res: $img.data('high_res')
        });
    });
});
```

Give that a shot.

Comment: thanks for your reply man, so far its been helpful. I've been able to get get the lighbox to open up which is good, however, no image is being displayed. I've tried both variations, the one on your fiddle and also the one you've written up on your answer.

window.parent.Tumblr.Lightbox.init(photo_{PostID});

Also the other variation with:

window.parent.Tumblr.Lightbox.init(this);

Any idea why its not pulling the image ?
Big thanks so far man!

Comment: I don't know anything about how tumblr works, I just answered the question about wrapping up the functionality. Sorry.

Comment: Okay cool, well ill put it this way, is there a way to target the image tag and also the #ID of the image or instead of targeting img tags, target a #ID ? e.g <img id="photo_123" src="#" /> in short. I've tried $('img#photo_{PostID}')  but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: sorry for all the questions, just that even though your answer was jquery, it's working because the lightbox happens to be appearing, so i really want to use your answer.